# Why cant any fields exert force on a stationary charged particle?

Tags: magnetic-fields, electric-fields

Can any fields exert force on a stationary charge?

Comment: An electric field and gravity will both exert a force.

Comment: It is not clear what you're asking - the title asks about the reasons for something that simply isn't true, while the body asks for examples, but you already *tagged your question* [tag:electric-fields] - an example of such a field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Electric and gravitational fields do exert force but magnetic field wouldn't.